# Recursive function in Python throwing an error

Tags: python, recursion

Trying to do this question I got on leetcode.com in python:

Given a sorted (in ascending order) integer array nums of n elements and a target value, write a function to search target in nums. If target exists, then return its index, otherwise return -1.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [-1,0,3,5,9,12], target = 9
Output: 4
Explanation: 9 exists in nums and its index is 4

Example 2:

Input: nums = [-1,0,3,5,9,12], target = 2
Output: -1
Explanation: 2 does not exist in nums so return -1

Note:

1. You may assume that all elements in nums are unique.
2. n will be in the range [1, 10000].
3. The value of each element in nums will be in the range [-9999, 9999].

FIRST ATTEMPT

```
class Solution(object):
    count = 0;
    def search(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if (nums[count] == target):
            return count;
        elif(count +1 >len(nums)):
            return -1;
        else:
            count += 1;
            return search(self, nums, target);
```

My Second attempt was the same exact code except the following line:
count = 0;
was put right after the function definition:
def search(self, nums, target):

Input:

nums = [-1,0,3,5,9,12]
target = 9

Expected Answer: 4

(First Attempt) Actual Answer: 
Line 10: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

(Second Attempt) Actual Answer:
Line 16: NameError: global name 'search' is not defined

I looked up recursive functions with python on the web and it didn't offer too much help as all the example code is more or less the same. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your problems have nothing to do with recursion, but rather with misuse of class members.

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment` means that you use `return count` and `count += 1`, but never initialized it to anything. Presumably, you either want to do `count = 0` in the method body, or use `self.count` instead.

`NameError: global name 'search' is not defined` is because you're calling a class method wrong. `self` is special on class methods, so instead of `search(self, nums, target)`, do `self.search(nums, target)`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any need to use a class here at all, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use self.search and also I think there is a better way to solve the problem

The question is basically related to **Binary Search**. You can learn more about it at this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/

I am also attaching the code in Python for reference along with test data. Hope it helps

```
def binarySearch (nums, left, right, target):
if right >= left:
    mid = left + (right - left)/2
    if nums[mid] == target: 
        return mid 
    elif nums[mid] > target: 
        return binarySearch(nums, left, mid-1, target) 
    else: 
        return binarySearch(nums, mid + 1, right, target) 
else: 
    return -1

nums = [-1,0,3,5,9,12]
target = 9
result = binarySearch(nums, 0, len(nums)-1, target) 
print result
```